# Suggestions on Structuring a Database with Large Amounts of Data

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm doing an RIA with JavaScript, MySQL and PHP on a Windows server.

I have 5,000 identically structured data sets I want to put in a database.  5 tables is enough for the data, all of which will be reasonably small except for one table that will have 300,000+ records for a typical data set.

Additionally, 500 users will get read only access to statistics compiled from those data sets.  Those statistics are provided by PHP (no direct access is allowed).  What's more, their access to data varies.  Some users can only use one data set, others some, a few, all.

The results users see are relatively small; most requests return well under 100 rows, and the largest requests will be about 700 rows.  All requests are through a JavaScript RIA which uses Ajax to connect to PHP which in turn connects to the data, does its thing and outputs JSON in response, which JavaScript then presents accordingly.

In thinking about how to structure this, three options present themselves:

1. Put the data sets in the same tables.  That could easily give me 1,500,000,000 records in the largest table.
2. Use separate tables for each data set.  That would limit the largest table size, but could mean 25,000 tables.
3. Forget the database and stick with the proprietary format.

I'm leaning towards #2 for a few reasons.

1. I'm concerned about issues in using very large tables (eg: query speeds, implementation limits, etc...).
2. Separate tables seem safer; they limit the impact of errors and structure changes.
3. Separate tables allow me to use MySQL's table level security rather than implementing my own row level security.  This means less work and better protection; for instance, if a query is accidentally sent without row level security, users can get unauthorized data.  Not so with table level security, as the database will reject the query out of hand.

Those are my thoughts, but I'd like yours.  Do you think this is the right choice?  If not, why not?  What considerations have I missed?  Should I consider other platforms if scale-ability is an issue?

Comment: mysql does support partitioning: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

Comment: Thanks.  I am researching this.  Partition-level security (if possible) would rock :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) I'm concerned about issues in using very large tables (eg: query speeds, implementation limits, etc...).

Whether the DBMS has to...

- search through the large index of one table,
- or search for the right table and *then* search through the smaller index of that table

...probably doesn't make much of a difference performance-wise. If anything, the second case has an undocumented component (the performance of locating the right table), so I'd be reluctant to trust it fully.

If you want to physically partition the data, MySQL [supports that directly](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/partitioning.html) since version 5.1, so you don't have to emulate it via separate tables.

> 2) Separate tables seem safer; they limit the impact of errors and structure changes.

That's what backups are for.

> 3) Separate tables allow me to use MySQL's table level security rather than implementing my own row level security.

True enough, however similar effect can be achieved through views or stored procedures.

All in all, my instinct is to go with a single table, unless you know in advance that these data-sets differ enough structurally to warrant separate tables. BTW, I doubt you'd be able to do better with a proprietary format compared to a well-optimized database.

Comment: Thank you; those are good points.  Regarding finding the right table, I was simply going to name the table by the data set (each data set has a unique name) and build it into the string in a PHP query (eg: "SELECT $dataSet FROM ...").  I agree that backups give us a level of protection, but until the restoration is made, the impact is still an issue, so restricting the initial hit is best.